# Pythonic way of iterating over 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, loops

I have a 3D array in Python and I need to iterate over all the cubes in the array.  That is, for all `(x,y,z)` in the array's dimensions I need to access the cube:

```
array[(x + 0, y + 0, z + 0)]
array[(x + 1, y + 0, z + 0)]
array[(x + 0, y + 1, z + 0)]
array[(x + 1, y + 1, z + 0)]
array[(x + 0, y + 0, z + 1)]
array[(x + 1, y + 0, z + 1)]
array[(x + 0, y + 1, z + 1)]
array[(x + 1, y + 1, z + 1)]
```

The array is a Numpy array, though that's not really necessary.  I just found it very easy to read the data in with a one-liner using `numpy.fromfile()`.

Is there any more Pythonic way to iterate over these than the following?  That simply looks like C using Python syntax.

```
for x in range(x_dimension):
    for y in range(y_dimension):
        for z in range(z_dimension):
            work_with_cube(array[(x + 0, y + 0, z + 0)],
                           array[(x + 1, y + 0, z + 0)],
                           array[(x + 0, y + 1, z + 0)],
                           array[(x + 1, y + 1, z + 0)],
                           array[(x + 0, y + 0, z + 1)],
                           array[(x + 1, y + 0, z + 1)],
                           array[(x + 0, y + 1, z + 1)],
                           array[(x + 1, y + 1, z + 1)])
```

Comment: Will this be answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280667/in-python-is-there-an-easier-way-to-write-6-nested-for-loops ?

Comment: That would be range(...-1), here...

Comment: Actually, yes @tom10, it does answer the question

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Have a look at [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html), especially [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). You can compress the three loops into one with

```
import itertools

for x, y, z in itertools.product(*map(xrange, (x_dim, y_dim, z_dim)):
    ...
```

You can also create the cube this way:

```
cube = numpy.array(list(itertools.product((0,1), (0,1), (0,1))))
print cube
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1]])
```

and add the offsets by a simple addition

```
print cube + (10,100,1000)
array([[  10,  100, 1000],
       [  10,  100, 1001],
       [  10,  101, 1000],
       [  10,  101, 1001],
       [  11,  100, 1000],
       [  11,  100, 1001],
       [  11,  101, 1000],
       [  11,  101, 1001]])
```

which would to translate to `cube + (x,y,z)` in your case. The very compact version of your code would be

```
import itertools, numpy

cube = numpy.array(list(itertools.product((0,1), (0,1), (0,1))))

x_dim = y_dim = z_dim = 10

for offset in itertools.product(*map(xrange, (x_dim, y_dim, z_dim))):
    work_with_cube(cube+offset)
```

**Edit**: `itertools.product` makes the product over the different arguments, i.e. `itertools.product(a,b,c)`, so I have to pass `map(xrange, ...)` with as `*map(...)`

Comment: This results in the error:
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Comment: ...However, using `(x,y,z)` instead of `offset` in your example fixes that

Comment: What does the `*` in `*map(...)` do?

Comment: @Nathan: it calls the function with a list as the arguments. `s=[1,2,3]; foo(*s)` is the same as `foo(1,2,3)`

Comment: as opposed to `foo(s)` which would pass `foo` only one argument, the list `s`?

Comment: I see a problem with your suggested solution.  X is my LSB.  In the original question you can see that it flips at each line, while in your suggested example it's the MSB, since it flips only once, in the middle of the list.  How can I generate the list `(0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,0),(1,1,0) etc...`?

Comment: reverse every vector with `[v[::-1] for v in itertools.product((0,1), (0,1), (0,1))]`

Answer (score 8):

```
import itertools
for x, y, z in itertools.product(xrange(x_size), 
                                 xrange(y_size), 
                                 xrange(z_size)):
    work_with_cube(array[x, y, z])
```