# Python: Better way to write nested for loops and if statements

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-for-loop

I am trying to find a more Pythonic way of doing the below.

```py
for employee in get_employees:
    for jobs in employee['jobs']:
        for nemployee in employee_comps:
            if nemployee['employee_id'] == employee['id']:
                for njob in nemployee['hourly_compensations']:
                    if njob['job_id'] == jobs['id']:
                        njob['rate'] = jobs['rate']
```

It works but seems clunky. I'm new to Python, if there is another thread that will help with this please direct me there!

Comment: can you post the original data/dict?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the third loop. What is nemployee, employee_comps, njob? Can you elaborate more on the problem you're solving? I don't quite understands the structure of the dicts/lists you're working on.

Comment: Please post a snapshot of your data.

Comment: Will this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1280667/327165

Comment: Looking at what you are trying to do this seems to be the logical way.   You could do some preprocessing of the data so you could avoid the "search the entire array to find a match" logic, then use dictionaries to avoid the search loops.  But since you don't break out of loops when the match is made, I have to assume each loop could have multiple matches.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In python is there an easier way to write 6 nested for loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280667/in-python-is-there-an-easier-way-to-write-6-nested-for-loops)

Comment: This seems like the kind of task that would be better-served using a database, by doing JOIN/WHERE type operations. Or, at least, a DataFrame that can serve as an in-memory pseudo-database. [`pandas`](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/) is the foremost python dataframe library, and is probably worth looking into, if you can structure your data into a format that's friendly to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main comment I would make about the code is that you are free to change the order of the outer three `for` loops because the operation that you are performing does not depend on the order that you loop over these (as you are not breaking out of any loops when finding a match), and that given that this is the case, there is no point in doing the `jobs` loop only to reach an `if` statement inside it that is independent of the value of `jobs`.  It would be more efficient to put the `jobs` loop inside the other two, so that it can also be inside the `if`, i.e. the loop is only performed for those combinations of values of `employee` and `nemployee` where the `if` condition evaluates `True`.

Beyond this but less importantly, where there are consecutive `for` statements (over independent iterables) after doing this rearrangement, you could replace them with a single loop over an  `itertools.product` iterator to reduce the depth of nesting of `for` loops if you wish (reducing it from four to two explicit loops):

```
from itertools import product

for employee, nemployee in product(get_employees, employee_comps):
    if nemployee['employee_id'] == employee['id']:
        for jobs, njob in product(employee['jobs'],
                                  nemployee['hourly_compensations']):
            if njob['job_id'] == jobs['id']:
                njob['rate'] = jobs['rate']
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is very clean and pythonic, I would suggest staying with that.

If you want it in one line, this *should* work, but I don't have data to test it on, so I'm not sure.

```py
[[njob.update({njob['rate']: jobs['rate']}) for njob in nemployee['hourly_compensations'] if njob['job_id'] == jobs['id']] for employee in get_employees for jobs in employee['jobs'] for nemployee in employee_comps if nemployee['employee_id'] == employee['id']]
```